# What is a more appropriate way of designing this solution?

Tags: c#, linq

I am currently dealing with some code that works.  Really boils down to whether I should be making all these ?blind? casts.

I have a class:

```
public abstract class Trigger
{
  // no logic, just three automatic properties
}
```

which is inherited by:

```
// there are several classes like this that store different things like strings,
// int,floats, enums, etc,etc.
public class ActivateOnTimeDelay : Trigger
{
   // More automatic properties and possibly fields.
}
```

I then place these classes into a `List<Trigger>`

and in another class iterate over the list in a reverse for loop

```
if (currentMission.ActiveTriggers.Count > 0)
{
  for (int i = currentMission.ActiveTriggers.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
   ActivateOnDeathDelay activateOnDeathD = currentMission.ActiveTriggers[i] as    ActivateOnDeathDelay;
   ActivateOnDeathImmediate activateOnDeathI = currentMission.ActiveTriggers[i] as ActivateOnDeathImmediate;
   ActivateOnFinishDelay activateOnFinishD = currentMission.ActiveTriggers[i] as ActivateOnFinishDelay;
   ActivateOnFinishImmediate activateOnFinishI = currentMission.ActiveTriggers[i] as ActivateOnFinishImmediate;
   ActivateOnFinishMass activateOnFinishM = currentMission.ActiveTriggers[i] as ActivateOnFinishMass;
   ActivateOnTimeDelay activateOnTimeD = currentMission.ActiveTriggers[i] as ActivateOnTimeDelay;
   ActivateOnTimeImmediate activateOnTimeI = currentMission.ActiveTriggers[i] as ActivateOnTimeImmediate;

   DisplayDialog displayDialog = currentMission.ActiveTriggers[i] as DisplayDialog;
   SpawnEnemy spawnEnemy = currentMission.ActiveTriggers[i] as SpawnEnemy;

   if (activateOnDeathD != null)
   {
     // do logic
   }

   // more null checks for each possible item that may be created this loop pass.
```

When a Trigger is used it is removed from the list and its ID is placed into a `HashSet<string>` UsedTriggers that some triggers watch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general what should happen here is that `Trigger` (or perhaps an `ITrigger` interface) exposes abstract methods that each concrete type of trigger implements appropriately. This way you don't need to cast, you just do something like

```
for (int i = currentMission.ActiveTriggers.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    // Run() is an abstract method on Trigger
    currentMission.ActiveTriggers[i].Run();
}
```

or, perhaps even better with LINQ (improved readability):

```
foreach (var trigger in currentMission.ActiveTriggers.Reverse())
{
    trigger.Run();
}
```